# CSS @import not Resolved in SVG on Firefox if SVG is Embedded in HTML Via <img> Tag

Tags: html, css, svg, firefox, microsoft-edge

I'm getting strange behavior on Firefox (78.5.0esr) regarding SVG content embedded into HTML via the `<img>` tag.
The SVG contains a reference to an external style sheet via the CSS "@import" directive like so:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-64 -64 128 128">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
            @import url('../css/rds.css');
            path {
                stroke: var(--error-color);
            }
        ]]></style>
    </defs>
    <path d="M -48 -48 L 48 48 M -48 48 L 48 -48"/>
</svg>
```

Now, if I open this SVG in Firefox directly, everything seems to work fine, the rules from rds.css are imported and honored OK.
But if I embed this SVG into an HTML page via the img tag like so:

```
<img src="delete.svg"/>
```

the SVG itself seems to have been loaded correctly into the page, but the @import inside the SVG's CSS seems to have been ignored.
If I remove the "@import" directive and put the CSS code directly into the SVG, it is rendering fine in all contexts.

Interestingly, the same seems to happen on MS Edge.
Am I missing something here? Is there a security setting preventing the loading of secondarily-linked content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<img>` files must be entirely self-contained for privacy reasons, i.e. they can't refer to any external files.

You'd have to include all the styles inline in the file itself if you want this to work as @import won't work in an image context.